# Как проверить, при загрузки файла, что он действительно является картинкой?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, ckeditor, pillow

Загружаю с помощью ckeditor изображение, по факту могу подсунуть любой файл, как сделать так, что бы для начала проверить его, а уж после загрузить на сервер? 
вот часть вьюхи, я так понимаю нужно как-то валидизацию провести, с помощью pillow

```
form = PostForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=post)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
```

Я так понимаю, что он загружается через RichTextUploadingField в моделе или в форме через виджет CKEditorUploadingWidget

Comment: Могу ведь вместо фото любой файл подсунуть, а хотелось бы, что бы пользователь мог только фото добавить.

Comment: В `ImageField` невозможно загрузить то, что не является изображением. При попытке получите `ValidationError('Файл, который вы загрузили, поврежден или не является изображением.')`

Comment: Огромное спасибо за ваш ответ, много ваших ответов читал. Я так понимаю, что он загружается через RichTextUploadingField в моделе или в форме через виджет CKEditorUploadingWidget

Comment: Тогда в `settings.py` надо добавить `CKEDITOR_ALLOW_NONIMAGE_FILES = False`

Comment: Огромное, вам спасибо, вы великий человек. Вы правы.

Answer (score 1):

В `ImageField` невозможно загрузить то, что не является изображением. При попытке получите `ValidationError('Файл, который вы загрузили, поврежден или не является изображением.')` Чтобы добиться того же эффекта с полем `RichTextUploadingField`, в `settings.py` надо добавить `CKEDITOR_ALLOW_NONIMAGE_FILES = False`.